# Curly Brace glob order?

Tags: bash, glob

If I have two files (in a folder with similarly numbered files) such as

```
foo.18
foo.19
```

And I want to use a glob on them, do I do it like so:

```
cp -r /folder1/*.{19,20} /folder2/
```

or like so?

```
cp -r /folder1/{*.19,*.20} /folder2/
```

Neither seem to expand out when I tap <kbd>tab</kbd>.

Is one 'better than the other? What order does it expand in? Will it ever matter?

Comment: Are those numbers as intended?

Comment: For numeric brace expansions, you can also use `{0..N}`.

Comment: @ChrisDown does it work with double digits? I'm sure I've only seen it work with single digits at work.

Comment: @Pureferret At least on 4.2.45, yes. http://sprunge.us/VfOX

Comment: I think we must have a much older version than that.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Yes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, it doesn't matter. bash expands the glob *after* expanding the braces, so either will work.

```
$ tee foo bar baz </dev/null
$ echo *{a,o}*
bar baz foo
$ echo {*a*,*o*} 
bar baz foo
$ echo {*,*}
bar baz foo bar baz foo
```

Comment: And if you do want to do globbing here instead of expanding several globs after brace expansion, you can use `ksh` extended globbing with `echo *.@(19|29)` (enabled in `bash` with `shopt -s extglob`).